# React + Typescript styled components themeProvider props typing issue

Tags: reactjs, typescript, styled-components

I am trying to make StyledButton make use of VariantOptions objects, so interface of my components library is really clean, sadly im just starting with typescript and can't really figure this out. Keep in mind my types are probably wrong. It's probably really easy solution but I can't wrap my head around it.

I have object like this: [basing on this i can choose variant of button]

```
const variantOptions: IvariantOptions = {    
    primary: {
        backgroundColor: theme?.colors.primary || '',
//more stuff here
    },
    secondary: {
        backgroundColor: theme?.colors.secondary || '',

    }
//more possible keys
}
```

And here is variant StyledButton - from styled components:

```
const StyledButton = styled.button<ButtonProps>`
padding: 10px 20px;
outline: none;
&:hover {
    cursor: pointer
}

${({ variant }) => 
    variant &&
    variantOptions[variant] &&
    css`
background-color: ${variantOptions[variant].backgroundColor};

`}
`;
```

And I created bunch of interfaces (probably overcomplicated this)

```
interface ButtonProps extends IvariantOptions  {
  variant: keyof IvariantOptions;
  variantOptions?: IvariantOptions;     
 }

interface Ivariant {
    [variant: string]: string;
}

interface IvariantOptions {
    primary: Ivariant,
    secondary: Ivariant
    }


interface IKey {
[key:string]:string;
}

interface ITheme {
    [key:string]:IKey;
}

interface IButtonProps {
    variant?: string;
    children?: React.ReactNode | string;
    theme?: ITheme;
}
```

That's my definition of this Button components.

```
export const Button = ({variant="primary",children, theme,...props}: IButtonProps) => {
//return button here
  return (
        <StyledButton variant={variant}>
{   children }
            </StyledButton>
    )
}
}
```

Sadly after all this typings, variant can't fit into string and TS is saying that:

> "Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'keyof IvariantOptions'

That's actually true, but in all that typing I can't figure out how to do it. Variant is not string but in the end I want it looks like this:

```
<Button variant="primary"/>
<Button variant="secondary"/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your interface IButtonProps should define as variant `keyof IvariantOptions` to fix this issue:

```
interface IButtonProps {
    variant?: keyof IvariantOptions;
    children?: React.ReactNode | string;
    theme?: ITheme;
}
```

on the other side you should remove your extends IvariantOptions, otherwise it will complain about missing props `primary` and `secondary`:

```
interface ButtonProps {
  variant: keyof IvariantOptions;
  variantOptions?: IvariantOptions;     
}
```

Comment: It fixed my issue, thank you really much.